# Need to display infinite alert strip. Currently, only first three alert strip are visible

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently only 3 alert strip is getting displayed instead of 5.Eventually I am going to display nth number of alert strip.So, I am trying to code in such manner that even if there are 5 alert strip or nth number of alert strip all should get displayed.

I am using CSS to for movement of the strip.

So,currently 1st alert,2nd alert, 3rd alert then again 1st alert, 2nd alert and so on is getting displayed.

Link of video discribing the issue -
https://youtu.be/boI18A24dBs

HTML -

```
<div class="marquee">
        <ul class="marquee-content">
          <li>
              <v-alert
                class="alertStrip"
                border="left"
                close-text="Close Alert"
                color="deep-purple accent-4"
                dark
                dismissible
                text-align="center"
                v-model="alert"
              >
                <b>This is v-alert One</b>
              </v-alert>
          </li>
          <li>
            <v-alert
              class="alertStrip"
              border="left"
              close-text="Close Alert"
              color="deep-purple accent-4"
              dark
              dismissible
              text-align="center"
              v-model="alert"
            >
              <b>This is v-alert Two</b>
            </v-alert>
          </li>
          <li>
            <v-alert
              class="alertStrip"
              border="left"
              close-text="Close Alert"
              color="deep-purple accent-4"
              dark
              dismissible
              text-align="center"
              v-model="alert"
            >
              <b>This is v-alert Three</b>
            </v-alert>
          </li>
          <li>
            <v-alert
              class="alertStrip"
              border="left"
              close-text="Close Alert"
              color="deep-purple accent-4"
              dark
              dismissible
              text-align="center"
              v-model="alert"
            >
              <b>This is v-alert Four</b>
            </v-alert>
          </li>
          <li>
            <v-alert
              class="alertStrip"
              border="left"
              close-text="Close Alert"
              color="deep-purple accent-4"
              dark
              dismissible
              text-align="center"
              v-model="alert"
            >
              <b>This is v-alert Five</b>
            </v-alert>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

CSS -

```
.alertStrip {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  text-align: center;
}
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.marquee:before,
.marquee:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}
.marquee:before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f5f5f5 0%, transparent 100%);
}
.marquee:after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #f5f5f5 0%, transparent 100%);
}
.marquee-content {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  animation: scrolling 20s linear infinite;
}
.marquee-content:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes scrolling {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-180vw);
  }
  // 100% { transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--marquee-element-width) * var(--marquee-elements))); }
}
.marquee-content li {
  display: flex;
  width: 80vw;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 5rem; /* 5rem; */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

How can I be able to display all the v-alert?

Comment: My guess is, the remaining two alerts appeared but are hidden behind the 3 alerts which already occupy the screen height of 7% (your css). Because all v-alert are bonded with the same v-model so it could not happen that only the 3 will be displayed among of 5. To test this guess, try different v-model for each alert and check their status in the Vue debugger or console.

Comment: The animation is clearly resetting before traveling the full width of all the v-alerts.  with your current method of animation, you'll want to modify the translateX to a large enough value that shows all the v-alerts before the reset.  I personally would rather use a library to create the marquee effect, especially if the goal is to be dynamic.  if you google "vue infinite marquee" you'll find plenty of options and examples.

Comment: @NehaSoni I tried with different v-model for each alert but not working. Also if you see in video 4th alert was about to come but got reset. So, I think might be width issue?

Comment: @yoduh I tried with that as well but didn't go appropriate answer. Will try again

Comment: Maybe you can provide a working fiddle so we can play there.

Comment: Okay! Give me some time.I will create one

Comment: https://codepen.io/KiranGire/pen/poZWyPx